# Angular UI State Params - Browser Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

This may have been answered already (if yes please point me to the right place), else please let me know if you have any working solution.

I am using angularjs 1.5.5, angular-ui-router 0.4.2 and running into an issue (may be implementation specific), when refreshing the browser.

Here is a sample pseudo routing code that defines state and what goes on to bring data for the states that can then be used in the controller.

```
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
    // An array of state definitions
    var states = [    
     { 
       name: 'checkout', 
       url: '/checkout',
       templateUrl: 'app/checkout/view/checkout.html',
       controller: 'checkoutController'     

     },

     { 
       name: 'confirm-checkout', 
       url: '/confirmcheckout', 
       params: {model: checkoutModel},
       templateUrl: 'app/checkout/view/confirmcheckout.html',
       controller :'checkoutConfirmationController',
       resolve: {
       person: function(people, $stateParams) {
           return someService.someApi($stateParams.model)
       }
     }
   }
  ]

  // Loop over the state definitions and register them
     states.forEach(function(state) {
       $stateProvider.state(state);
     });
  });
```

As you can see the /confirmcheckout url, depends on the data fed by the stateParams. Let's say we navigate to the /confirmcheckout url (via the router, that displays the confirmcheckout.html properly with all data resolved via the someService.someApi call. At this point, if I refresh the browser, angularjs will reinitialize the javascript models / services etc. That means, my stateParams will be lost and the page confirmcheckout.html will lose all data. How to handle page refresh in such scenarios. Session Storage and Local Storage are discouraged https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security (see Using Local Caches )

Here is how the transition is happening in the application from checkout to confirmcheckout.

$state.go('confirmcheckout', {model:someModel});

In a nut shell, how do I implement browser refresh for states that rely on stateparams for rendering the UI ?

Comment: `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` are used extensively for state maintenance. If you have sensitive data on the view (credit card #), there is no secure way to save/restore that on the client(browser).

Answer (score 0):

You can save use query parameter in URL.

In our case

```
   url: '/confirmcheckout?model',
```

See https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/params.paramtypes.html#query

Comment: Can you reproduce the minimum code to resolve this and post it as part of your answer? That link may die and without, your answer as-is would not be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I've added an example of url param.

Comment: Please see my comment on how the transition is happening between checkout and confirmcheckout. Please note: the confirmcheckout is a readonly page, that is populated using the model from the stateParams in the resolve member of the state.

Comment: @Tams, did you try to use reload option?

`$state.go(('confirmcheckout', {model:someModel}, {reload: true, notify: true})`